# In React, can a Parent class access fields from a Child class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, inheritance

I am learning React. In a tutorial I saw online regarding handling Form submissions, there is a component **Form** which is being extended by another component **LoginForm**.

**Form.jsx**:

```
import { React, Component } from "react";
import Joi from "joi-browser";

class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {},
    errors: {},
  };

  validate = () => {
    const options = { abortEarly: false };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(this.state.data, this.schema, options); 
    if (!error) return null;

    const errors = {};
    for (let item of error.details) errors[item.path[0]] = item.message;
    return errors;
  };

  validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
    const obj = { [name]: value };
    const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };

    const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
    return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const errors = this.validate();
    this.setState({ errors: errors || {} });
    if (errors) return;

    this.doSubmit();
  };

  handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    const errorMessage = this.validateProperty(input);
    if (errorMessage) errors[input.name] = errorMessage;
    else delete errors[input.name];

    const data = { ...this.state.data };
    data[input.name] = input.value;

    this.setState({ data, errors });
  };
}

export default Form;
```

**LoginForm.jsx**:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./common/form";
import Joi from "joi-browser";
import Input from "./common/input";

class LoginForm extends Form {
  state = {
    data: { username: "", password: "" },
    errors: {},
  };

  schema = {
    username: Joi.string().required().label("Username"),
    password: Joi.string().required().label("Password"),
  };

  doSubmit = () => {
    // call the server
    console.log("Submitted");
  };

  render() {
    const { data, errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Input
            name="username"
            value={data.username}
            label="Username"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            error={errors.username}
          />
          <Input
            name="password"
            value={data.password}
            label="Password"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            error={errors.password}
          />
          <button disabled={this.validate()} className="btn btn-primary">
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Since LoginForm is extending Form, in the `validate()` function, how can Form be using properties like this.schema, if schema is defined in LoginForm.jsx?

Comment: It can't; inheritance only goes one way. This pattern exists so you can make multiple extensions of a form without too much repeating of code. You could create a `ContactForm`, a `NewsSubscribeForm`, or any kind of form that requires that existing logic of `Form`.

Comment: One way to solve this idea is to Lifting State Up
` (Google/Youtube it): https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#:~:text=In%20React%2C%20sharing%20state%20is,it%20into%20the%20Calculator%20instead.